# How to detect that i reached the last postion of getSelectedItem of spinner after certain time

Tags: android, android-spinner

I change spinner item after certain interval using the following method: 
`spinner.setSelection(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()+1);`
When all item fetching completed app is crashed. Please assist me in order to determine when I've reached the last position of spinner item

Comment: Please share the error + your code for further assistance

Comment: IndexOutBoundError

Comment: If you have the exact size of the list then put the length check. Let say you have list then write this line, if(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() < list.length) or you can get the spinner count with the following line : spinner.getAdapter().getCount()

Comment: I get java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get items count in spinner:

```
mSpinner.getAdapter().getCount();
```